# What could be a non-integrated call of an inline function in C?

Tags: c, gcc, inline

About inline functions in C, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) documentation says that,

> When a function is both inline and static, if all calls to the function are integrated into the caller, and the function’s address is never used, then the function’s own assembler code is never referenced. In this case, GCC does not actually output assembler code for the function, unless you specify the option -fkeep-inline-functions. **If there is a nonintegrated call**, then the function is compiled to assembler code as usual. The function must also be compiled as usual if the program refers to its address, because that cannot be inlined.

First case is clear: If all the calls are integrated into the caller, then there is no need to produce the assembler code.

But what could be a **non integrated call**?

A function can be not suitable for inlining, but how come a function call become so?

Comment: ? You want the resulting executable to be small, and the function is called more than once.

Comment: Whether a function is suitable for inlining could depend on not just the function itself but on the call site, I imagine, as different call sites would have different registers available. If any calls aren't replaced, then the function must be included.

Comment: A nonintegrated function call is simply an ordinary function call—the arguments are pushed into the stack, and a call instruction is executed to transfer control to the function, while providing the return address for the subsequent return instruction. A function call is either integrated (code to execute the function is inserted at the call site) or nonintegrated (code to call the function is inserted at the call site)…

Comment: … Your sentence “A function can be not suitable for inlining, but how come a function call become so?” suggests maybe you think a nonintegrated call would mean the actual call instruction is not in the calling function. But it is; “nonintegrated” here refers to whether the function being called is integrated into the calling function, not whether the call instruction is integrated into the calling function.

Comment: Maybe the call is in a rare code path, so the optimizer prefers to reduce size by not copying the function. (Not sure if this actually happens)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I get what you're saying. thanks. Am I right to assume that the "non-integration" depends on the call site? Not on the function? Additionally can I predict it?

Comment: @NisalBandara: I do not know specifically what compilers to make inline integration decisions. I would expect, or not be surprised, if it depends on how much code is required to inline the function (or the size of the non-lined version of the function), whether `-Os` (to optimize space) is specified, some internal models the compiler has about target system behaviors (or equivalent knowledge that has been incorporated into the compiler), whether the compiler judges the code to be in a critical path and so on.

Comment: E.g., suppose the code looks like `MyFunction(stuff); for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { MoreStuff(OtherStuff); }`. If the compiler knows `MyFunction` is a “short” function, it might reason that there is little to gain from inlining it since calling `MoreStuff` a million times will dominate execution time. I do not know what compilers do in this regard nowadays.

Comment: You never know until you look into the generated code and/or map. `inline` is more a hint than a requirement to the compiler. Some years ago we had a lot of trouble to stop the compiler from inlining a function, and finally we had to use compiler specific pragmas. It all depends on the compiler, its options you give to it, the optimization algorithms, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> A function can be not suitable for inlining, but how come a function call become so?

There are several possibilities:

### 1. Taking the Address of the Function

In general, if taking the address of a function, for example to build a dispatch table, then the compiler can't optimize the *"take address + indirect call*" back to *"dirett call"*.  Simple example:

```cpp
static inline int inc (int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}

int (*pfunc)(int) = inc;
```

### 2. Inlining the Function makes the Code more expensive

The cost model of the compiler is not perfect, and code inlining usually happens in an early stage of compilation, which consists of several hundred passes in the case of GCC.  This means that the cost computation might be way off the actual costs of the final code due to inexact estimates of code size, register pressure, call overhead, costs of stack frame, benefit of value propagation, etc.

This may lead to the conclusion that inlining the function will decrease code performance compared to non-inlined version of the code.

This typically happens when optimizing for code size (`-Os`). You can use `-Winline` to diagnose such situations.  Sometimes the code is actually worse, but you still want the inlined version because you prefer speed over size in that place, even when using `-Os`.  And sometimes the cost model of the compiler is not 100% correct.

In this case of *"not suitable for inlining"* you can add `__attribute__((__always_inline__))` and the compiler will inline the function — if not prohibited otherwise — even when optimization is turned off.